# Create a single CSV string out of a spark dataframe column containing csv values

Tags: apache-spark

I have df like below:

```
df.show()

1,2
1,4 
1,4,5
```

The data frame have only 1 column and 3 records each having csv string and I want to create following csv string out of above dataframe:

```
1,2,4,5
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the output, you should collect it on the driver. To do that, use flatMap & toLocalIterator to retrieve elements as a list.

Here is an example:

```
def csv2rows(x):  
    for ele in x.split(','):  
      yield ele  
df.flatMap(csv2rows).distinct().toLocalIterator()
```